# determining average grades and displaying letter grades

Tags: python, average

I'm working on a program for class that finds the average of 5 entered test scores then displays the letter grades relevant to each letter score. letter score is a 10 point system ( A = 90-100 B = 80-89, etc)

This is what I've put together so far but it doesn't seem to recognize "avg" in the syntax. any suggestions?

```
def main():
    while true:
        grade = int(input('Enter grade: '))
        total += grade
        avg = calc_average(total)
        abc_grade = determine_grade(grade)

        print('Average grade is: ' avg)
        print('Letter grades for entered grades are: ' abc_grade)

    def calc_average(total):
       return total / 5

    def determine_grade(grade):
        if grade >= 90 and <= 100:
            return 'A'
        elif grade >= 80 and <= 89:
            return 'B'
        elif grade >= 70 and <= 79:
            return 'C'
        elif grade >= 60 and <= 69:
            return 'D'
        else:
            return 'F'

main()
```

Comment: Please explain **it doesn't seem to recognize `"avg"` in the syntax**?

Comment: python returns "invalid syntax" then highlights "avg" in the code window.

Comment: Grades are always going to be integers?

Comment: yeah, i seem to have to whole thing mucked up. every time an adjustment is made, I seem to dig a deeper hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_list = []


def calc_average(total):
    return total / 5


def determine_grade(grade):
    if grade >= 90 and grade <= 100:
        return 'A'
    elif grade >= 80 and grade <= 89:
        return 'B'
    elif grade >= 70 and grade <= 79:
        return 'C'
    elif grade >= 60 and grade <= 69:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'


while True:
    grade = int(input('Enter grade: '))
    _list.append(grade)

    avg = calc_average(sum(_list))
    abc_grade = ' '.join([determine_grade(mark) for mark in _list])

    if len(_list) > 5:
        break

print('Average grade is: ', avg)
print('Letter grades for entered grades are: ', abc_grade)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Is there a way to list each separate letter grade without using _list to store grades?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to avoid the `_list`, but since `grade` is being one variable, its being overwritten all the time when you perform the loop operation. So, you should persist `grade`, and you can do this by other data structure also

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
    print('Average grade is: '+str(avg))
    print('Letter grades for entered grades are: '+abc_grade)
```

or

```
    print('Average grade is: %.2f'%(avg))
    print('Letter grades for entered grades are: %s'%(abc_grade))
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me.. A few minor changes except your code is working fine.

```
def main():
    total = 0;avg = 0;abc_grade = 0

def calc_average(total):
    return total / 5

def determine_grade(grade):
    if 90 <= grade <= 100:
        return 'A'
    elif 80 <= grade <= 89:
        return 'B'
    elif 70 <= grade <= 79:
        return 'C'
    elif 60 <= grade <= 69:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'

while(True):
    grade = int(input('Enter grade: '))
    total += grade
    avg = calc_average(total)
    abc_grade = determine_grade(grade)

    print('Average grade is: ' + str(avg))
    print('Letter grades for entered grades are: ' + str(abc_grade))


main()
```

Hope you can find out differences. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():

  print("This is a program which displays the grade from a score")

  print("")

  grade = eval(input("What is the value of the score :  "))

  print("")

  if 90 <= grade <= 100:
    print("Your get an A")

  elif 80 <= grade <= 89:
    print("Your get a B")
  elif 70 <= grade <= 79:
    print("Your get a C")
  elif 60 <= grade <= 69:
    print("Your get a D")
  else:
    print("Your get an F")


main()
```